# Blender 2.8, missing a few things

Tags: 3d-view

I just downloaded blender 2.8 from the site, i was watching a tutorial and i noticed the tutorial had things i didn't in it. Im missing a wigets bar and a transform tool. All the red circled things.[image]

Comment: You are probably in the wrong Mode. Hit the Tab key and from the menu try to switch to Edit Mode or Object Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess since it is now possible to get 2.80 just following a link called "Try Blender 2.80 Beta" without scrolling down and reading all the red warnings this is a valid question.

Blender 2.80 has been in very active development for quite some time now. It is normal for things to change. It is still in beta version. Beta version means it is not yet released as finished software. Although they are now a bit easier to miss, the warnings at blender.org are still valid as well:

[image]

You still get some warnings while downloading and you get the explanation as well if you click on "Legend":

[image]

What you happened to observe here are changes during the development. Blender simply changed from the time the tutorials were made.